# How to create a UFW rule with helpful memo?

Tags: ufw

In the past I was able to create allow rules for ports with a helpful description, so I could remember why I allowed that specific port(s). I cannot for the life of me find on the web the command to do it again.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `comment` field:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 1234 comment 'my super secret service'
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
```

then

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
1234                       ALLOW       Anywhere                   # my super secret service
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1234 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # my super secret service
```